# Openstack instance launch with self signed certificate throwing nova api error

Tags: openstack, self-signed-certificate, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-keystone

trying to build a test environment with openstack:antelope on three nodes; controller, compute and networking. everything seems to be set up fine except i use a self-signed certificate and when i attempt to launch an instance from the command line i get the below error:

Unexpected API Error. Please report this at http:bugs.launchpad.net/nova/ and attach the Nova API log if possible. <class 'keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.SSLError'> (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-xxxxxxxxx)

openstack minimal software used on 3 ubuntu 22.04 server VM running in Hyper-V: 1 Controller has memcached, rabbitmq, mariadb, NTPserver, DNS (dnsmasq), keystone, glance, placement, nova-compute, nova-api, neutron server, neutron metadata. 2 Compute has NTPclient, QEMU/KVM(libvirt), nova-compute, neutron l2 agent, Open vSwitch 3 Network has NTPclient, Neutron l2/l3 agent, neutron metadata, Open vSwitch

all openstack commands ran with --insecure return results except for launching a server and all flags (insecure = true) set in config files. i looked at the nova api logs and it echos what i wrote above as the error. Any assistance or guidance to help resolve would be greatly appreciated, thanks much.

[openstack setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Jge.png)

[Nova api log tail -n 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwKaZ.png)

Tried these Openstack CLI command: 1st command: netID=$(openstack --insecure network list | grep private | awk '{ print $2 }') 2nd command: openstack --insecure server create --flavor m1.medium --image Ubuntu2204 --security-group secgroup01 --nic net-id=$netID --key-name mykey Ubuntu-2204

expected to have a VM server instance created and active... how ever failure. thanks for any help or guidance thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Go to your nova configuration file and add this line in the [Glance] section

`enable_certificate_validation = false`

Hopefully this will work